# C++ Templates and accessing namespaces

Tags: c++, class, templates, namespaces

Let's say I'm using a templated class with something simple like:

```
template <class T> 
class MyClass
```

I want to use elements from T's namespace, for example T could be string, and I wanted to use

```
T::const_iterator myIterator;
```

...or something like that. How do I achieve that?
Probably, it's either not possible or very simple, but I have no idea.

Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By default if `T` is a template parameter like in your example, the `T::some_member` is assumed not to name a type. You have to explicitly specify that it is, by prefixing it with `typename`:

```
typename T::const_iterator myIterator;
```

This resolves some parsing problems like in the following example

```
// multiplication, or declaration of a pointer?
T::const_iterator * myIterator;
```

So that the compiler can parse this even before instantiating the template, you have to give it a hand and use `typename`, including in those cases where it wouldn't be ambiguous, like in the first case above. The [Template FAQ](http://womble.decadentplace.org.uk/c++/template-faq.html) has more insight into this.

Comment: There is one case when "typename" doesn't have to be used (and can't be) : derivation, eg template<class T> class A : T::const_iterator {};

Answer (score 5):

It is definitely possible.

```
template< typename T >
class Example
{
    void foo( const T& t )
    {
        typedef typename T::value_type Type;
        typedef typename T::const_iterator Iter;
        Iter begin = t.begin();
        Iter end = t.end();

        std::copy( begin, end, std::ostream_iterator<Type>(std::cout) );
    }
};
```

The key is the typename part of the typedef.

Comment: Thank you too, making it an extra type for the whole class context seems a good idea.